# ImageSwitcher / Gallery with bullet point below the image

Tags: android

I am trying to put a ImageSwitcher and Gallery in my app, however, I want the gallery part just with some bullet points instead of the thumbnail of the original image.

Just for some more explanation to make it more clear.

Assume there are three image in my ImageSwitcher and there are three bullet point according to them.

When the first image is displayed, the first bullet point is colored while others are remain white. When the second image is displayed, the second bullet point is colored while other
are remain white...and so on.

I think that feature is quite common in many app or website, but I really don't know how to describe it with keywords. Hoping that someone can understand and give me a help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use View pager and corresponding third party library for indicators as  https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
library for view pager indicator and  view pager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html.

Comment: View pager is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: @neeni How's that different from what I've said?

Comment: Actually both of you really help me a lot, but I can only choose one answer...I'm sorry...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) instead of ImageSwitcher and Gallery widgets. [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) was deprecated since API level 16.